# Why do I see error while using pusher V6 with Laravel V8

Tags: php, laravel-8, pusher

I'm using Pusher version 6 with Laravel version 8. The problem is when I try to broadcast I see the following error.
As I checked this error doesn't happen in the lower version of Pusher

**TypeError
array_merge(): Argument #2 must be of type array, null given**

**My Code:**

```
class OrderStatusChanged implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public $order;

    public function __construct($order)
    {
        //
        $this->order = $order;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new Channel('my-channel');
    }
}
```

Please let me know if you find any solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should upgrade your Laravel version to v8.29.2, or downgrade your Pusher version to 4.1

Sources:
[Laravel Pusher array_merge: Expected parameter 2 to be an array, null given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66433624/laravel-pusher-array-merge-expected-parameter-2-to-be-an-array-null-given)
https://github.com/pusher/pusher-http-php/issues/288